# When does a deterministic function use the previous calculated value?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Consider a deterministic function like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SCHEMA.GET_NAME(ss_id nvarchar2)
  RETURN nvarchar2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
  tmpVar nvarchar2(500);
BEGIN
  select name into tmpvar from logistics.organization_items where id = ss_id ;
  return tmpvar ;  
END ss_name;
```

Using Toad I called the `SCHEMA.GET_NAME(1)` and it returns `A`. I then changed the value from the table from `A` to `B` and recalling the `SCHEMA.GET_NAME(1)` returned `B`.

It is a good result. But I'm afraid of the value not being updated according to [this page in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm), which said:

> When Oracle Database encounters a deterministic function in one of these contexts, it attempts to use previously calculated results when possible rather than reexecuting the function. If you subsequently change the semantics of the function, you must manually rebuild all dependent function-based indexes and materialized views.

In what situations would the value of `GET_NAME(1)` return an old cached value (`A` instead of `B`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you select from a table then the results of your function are *not* deterministic. A [deterministic system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_system) is one that will *always* produce the same output, given the same initial conditions.

It is possible to alter the information in a table, therefore a function that selects from a table is not deterministic. To quote from the [PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_function.htm#LNPLS1917):

> Do not specify this clause to define a function that uses package variables or that accesses the database in any way that might affect the return result of the function. The results of doing so are not captured if the database chooses not to reexecute the function.

In other words, Oracle does not guarantee that the results of the function will be accurate (they just might be). If your table is static, and unlikely to ever change, then it should be okay but this is not something I'd ever like to rely on. To answer your question, do not assume that Oracle will return anything other than the cached value within the same transaction/session.

If you need to speed this up there are two ways. Firstly, check that you have an index on `ID`!

1. Simply JOIN to this table. If your function is only this then there is no need for the function to exist.
2. Use [scalar sub-query caching](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51asktom-453438.html) (not necessarily possible but worth the try).

   ```
   select ( select get_name(:id) from dual )
      from your_table
   ```

   Oracle will create an in-memory hash of the results of the function, like a result cache. If you're executing the same function multiple times then Oracle will hit the cache rather than the function.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. Also I like to now how often the cache for this functions refreshes? In scope of executing a query? By a time interval? On memory demand to free the cache?

Comment: Or maybe caches are valid only during a session. So for a new session it will be updates?

Comment: @mehrandvd - I don't know the ins-and-outs of this feature, but I have a feeling it's like most other optimizations: it happens when the optimizer feels like it.  In other words, there's **NO WAY** to guarantee it being cached/updated (there's some probabilities, mostly with caching, but no guarantees).  This is similar to running a query without an `ORDER BY` - you get the order the optimizer decides to give you, not what you necessarily want/expect.

Comment: I've never actually read anything about how often the cache used for this is refreshed @mehrandvd. The result cache is refreshed when it's full, but I can't find much about what caching method is used for deterministic function.

Answer (score 1):

Ben's answer sums it up nicely, and I would just like to add that the way you used `DETERMINISTIC` keyword inside your function is not right - keeping in view that you are reading the value from a table and then returning the same to the user.

A deterministic function should be used in cases, where you are evaluating an expression over a fixed input, for example, when you need to return a substring, or upper/lower case for the input string. Programatically, you know that for the same input the lowercase function will always return the same value, and so you would like to cache the result (using deterministic keyword).

When you read a value from a table, Oracle has no way to know that the value in the column has not changed, and so it prefers to rexecute the function and not depend on the cached result (which makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a timestamp parameter to your function?  Then pass in sysdate to the function from wherever you're calling it.

This way, you're effectively caching the result and you avoid running the function over and over when it generally returns the same value within a given transaction.

Answer (score 0):

The remark of Erez is the answer I was looking for.
Before executing the query or plsql-unit you can with this solution force to execute the function again after you reseted the ret-values of the function (e.g. changing a package var).
I use this for: 
select ...
from   big_table_vw;

where

create view big_table_vw
as
select ... (analytical functions)
from big_table
where last_mutated >= get_date();

In my case the big_table_vw contains window-functions that prevents Oracle to push the predicate into the view.

Comment: Correction: I just tried to call the function many times without a timestamp and the result is that the function is called once for every sql-statement. So, a timestamp is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late follow-up to a long-answered question, but I just wanted to add that Oracle does provide a caching mechanism for functions with mutable dependencies.  `RESULT_CACHE` is an alternative to `DETERMINISTIC` that allows Oracle to abandon cached function results any time a referenced object is modified.

This way one can cache costly calculations against rarely-updated objects with confidence that cached results will not return incorrect results.

Here's an example using mythological monsters:

```
CREATE TABLE MONSTER (
  MONSTER_NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO MONSTER VALUES ('Chthulu');
INSERT INTO MONSTER VALUES ('Grendel');
INSERT INTO MONSTER VALUES ('Scylla');
INSERT INTO MONSTER VALUES ('Nue');
COMMIT;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MONSTER_PKG
IS
  FUNCTION IS_THIS_A_MONSTER(P_MONSTER_NAME IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN BOOLEAN RESULT_CACHE;
END MONSTER_PKG;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MONSTER_PKG
IS
  FUNCTION IS_THIS_A_MONSTER(P_MONSTER_NAME IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN BOOLEAN
  RESULT_CACHE RELIES_ON (MONSTER)
  IS
    V_MONSTER_COUNT NUMBER(1, 0) := 0;
    BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO V_MONSTER_COUNT
      FROM MONSTER
      WHERE MONSTER_NAME = P_MONSTER_NAME;
      RETURN (V_MONSTER_COUNT > 0);
    END;
END MONSTER_PKG;
/
```

When a scenario like the below occurs, any existing cache is invalidated and a new cache can then be rebuilt.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Is Kraken initially a monster?');
  IF MONSTER_PKG.IS_THIS_A_MONSTER('Kraken')
  THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Kraken is initially a monster');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Kraken is not initially a monster');
  END IF;
  INSERT INTO MONSTER VALUES ('Kraken');
  COMMIT;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Is Kraken a monster after update?');
  IF MONSTER_PKG.IS_THIS_A_MONSTER('Kraken')
  THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Kraken is now a monster');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Kraken is not now a monster');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

*Is Kraken initially a monster?

Kraken is not initially a monster

Is Kraken a monster after update?

Kraken is now a monster*